# How many threads do I have on my Python code?

Tags: python, linux, profile

I have a Python code that I want to profile with `nvprof` or `visual profiler`,
I want to know how many threads are used on my code?

I need Linux command.

Using this command:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 4 | egrep -i "Designation|Intel|core|thread"
```

Gets me this information, but it's not for my code:

```
Socket Designation: CPU1
Manufacturer: Intel
        HTT (Multi-threading)
Version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v3 @ 2.60GHz
Core Count: 14
Core Enabled: 14
Thread Count: 28
        Multi-Core
        Hardware Thread
Socket Designation: CPU2
Manufacturer: Intel
        HTT (Multi-threading)
Version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v3 @ 2.60GHz
Core Count: 14
Core Enabled: 14
Thread Count: 28
        Multi-Core
        Hardware Thread
```

I want to know how many threads my Python code uses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`threading.active_count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.active_count). From the documentation:

> Return the number of `Thread` objects currently alive. The returned count is equal to the length of the list returned by `enumerate()`.

From the documentation of [`threading.enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate):

> Return a list of all `Thread` objects currently alive. The list includes daemonic threads, dummy thread objects created by `current_thread()`, and the main thread. It excludes terminated threads and threads that have not yet been started.

Comment: thanks ,is there a command for linux terminal to find number of thread?or i shoud use that only in python code?

Comment: My answer shows you how to get the number of  threads from within the Python code.